# import paramiko throws '_sodium' has no function error

Tags: paramiko, nacl-cryptography, pynacl

> Importing paramiko throws following exception on Python3.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requirements_check.py", line 117, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 90, in <module>
    from paramiko.ed25519key import Ed25519Key
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/ed25519key.py", line 22, in <module>
    import nacl.signing
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nacl/signing.py", line 17, in <module>
    import nacl.bindings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nacl/bindings/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nacl.bindings.crypto_aead import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nacl/bindings/crypto_aead.py", line 28, in <module>
    lib.crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_ietf_keybytes()
AttributeError: cffi library '_sodium' has no function, constant or global variable named 'crypto_aead_chacha20poly1305_ietf_keybytes'
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you write which paramiko / cffi version you have installed, please?
Have you build them manually?

Comment: Version: paramiko==2.4.2 I think its something to do with nacl. Nope, its a pip3 install.

Answer (score 7):

Try uninstalling & reinstalling PyNaCl:

```
pip uninstall PyNaCl
pip install PyNaCl
```

Comment: For me, `pip uninstall PyNaCl` threw an error that it can't uninstall it '*outside environment /usr*', but `apt remove python3-nacl` then `pip install PyNaCl` did help.